# How to get the presentationStyle of iMessage Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10, xcode8, imessage

I am work around the UI Issues in the new iMessage extension framework. While transitioning from one presentation style to another I can easily tell the function to change the constant of one of my constraints, however this does not help if I am navigating the app from the expanded style. I have attempted to use

```
if (self.presentationStyle == .expanded){
    *Constraint code which works in other functions*
   }
```

Comment: So what is the issue? Did you try to use the function "didTransition" or "willTransition"?

Comment: Yes however once I go to another view and return it no longer works. My viewdidload is detecting the wrong presentationStyle

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller embedded in the iMessage app? In that case it's a bug from the sdk

Comment: I'm using the IMessage view controller, however I'm using button seques to navigate between them

Comment: Transitioning from another view in expanded mode, I set a switch to output the detected presentation style to the log, it detects compact mode even in expanded mode